# Why doesn't a bare repository have refs/heads/master?

Tags: git

I've got a bare repository, and it doesn't have an entry in `refs/heads` for `master`. Where is it storing this ref?

Comment: Is your repository also empty?  If there aren't any commits, there won't be any files in `refs/heads`.

Comment: @CarlNorum I just cloned one of my repositories into a bare repo, and there was nothing in `refs/heads`, even though there were three branches in the original.

Comment: Got it.  Answer coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the refs you're looking for in the `packed-refs` file.  See the [`git-pack-refs(1)` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html) for more.  Specifically:

> When a ref is missing from the traditional `$GIT_DIR/refs` directory hierarchy, it is looked up in this file and used if found.

Comment: "Got it. Answer coming." — how were you so sure? What was your method? Before posting, I also searched for an answer :D.

Comment: Oh, I just meant I understood what you did, and that I was about to write an answer.  Anyway, to find it, I just made a test repo, bare-cloned it, and did `ack -a c7aba8d30bcbb80e2ae1e2c089b13bd704d92258` in the bare clone to see where the hash was being stored.  It was in `packed-refs`, so I googled that file and found `git pack-refs`.